# Get content-length of FastAPI response

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

Im trying to get the content-length of FastAPI response on the server side for logging purpose. Is this possible? Thanks.

```
@app.get("/foo")
async def foo(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):

  data = {"foo": "foo"}

  response_content_length = get_content_length()

  background_tasks.add_task(log, response_content_length ) 

  return data
```

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own route by inheriting APIRoute class, now you should be able to log everything, without repeating yourself.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, Body, BackgroundTasks, APIRouter
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute

from typing import Callable, List



class ContextIncludedRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:

            response: Response = await original_route_handler(request)

            content_length = response.headers["content-length"]
            print(content_length)
            
            return response

        return custom_route_handler


app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter(route_class=ContextIncludedRoute)


@router.post("/dummy")
async def dummy():
    return {"foo":"foo"}


app.include_router(router)
```

Comment: Im talking about the response not the request, but its also helping for partly answer

Comment: Is there a way to get the value in the context of the same server call so Ill can know for which call it was?

Comment: Do you mean getting the `{"foo": "foo"}`?

Comment: I mean associate between the call for dummy() to the content_length so Ill can tight them together into a log line

Comment: do you mean the `response.body` what is associate i did not understand that part, what is the expected log line , maybe I can understand from that.

Comment: I want to know for each request to `dummy` what was the `content-length` related to this request.

Comment: As far as i understand you want to include the endpoint name to your logs, you can try `path = request.url.path` or `path = [route for route in request.scope['router'].routes if route.endpoint == request.scope['endpoint']][0].path`

Comment: My goal is to log what was the content length that was sent to the user. So if I have a path with `do_job` and the user pass parameter `x` and there another path with `do_job_2` and the user pass parameter `y` 
I want to log 1: what function was invoked. 2: what parameters passed. 3: what was the content length returned

Comment: check for `await request.body()` first if it is available add it,  if it is not it should have Query, check for `request.query_params` and add that to the logs, for the path you can use my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

@app.get("/foo")
async def foo(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    data = {"foo": "foo"}
    response = JSONResponse(data)
    response_content_length = response.headers["content-length"]
    background_tasks.add_task(log, response_content_length ) 
    return response
```